# AttributeError: event member not defined python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm just starting out and learning Python/PyGame. I'm currently following a tutorial but have run into the following error whenever a key is pressed:

```
File "wormy.py", line 134, in checkForKeyPress
  return keyUpEvents[0].keyUpEvents
AttributeError: event member not defined
```

The actual code in question is:

```
def checkForKeyPress():
    if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
        terminate()

keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
    if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
        return None

if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
    terminate()

return keyUpEvents[0].keyUpEvents
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: Does this similar question helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575274/attribute-error-member-not-defined-python

Comment: @afsharm Unfortunately, the similar question isn't really much help. I am rather new to python.pygame and this code snippet is an exact copy of a tutorial I was following so I'm unsure where it's gone wrong.